# Which MySQL partitioning is correct in my case?

Tags: mysql, bigdata, partitioning

We are operating an ad network and have some performance issues recently.

The table making problems is the table "clicks" with columns:
`click_id int`, `affiliate_id int`, `campaign_id int`, `country_id int`, `time datetime`.

All our Reads and Inserts have country_id in WHERE clause.

In Fact a clicks from one country always blocks the complete table for every other country too. This is not necessary and slows down our performance a lot.

Dear MySQL professionals, am I right to understand that partitioning the clicks table on country_id is a great solution for us?

I read about it in [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html)

But I'm not sure yet which Partitioning Type would be suitable for our needs.

Which one would you recommend and why?

Comment: depends on what queries you do with that table. But most probably partition by date - you can easily remove / archive old items.

Comment: What do you think about the idea to make a partition for each country?

Comment: is the country distribution even? If half the data is e.g. USA you won't gain much from partitioning by country.

Comment: No, it's not. We are currently in the USA and in UK, having 70 % and 30 %. Clicks on those countries are not related to each other. In fact we could even split it to two tables "clicks_usa" and "clicks_uk". So I thought partititiong could help us, did I get it wrong?

Comment: yes, but only for few months... what will you do when USA data will be as large as all data now? You would need to partition by something else anyway... The question is: what are you trying to solve by partitioning? Slow INSERTs? SELECTs? DELETEs? INSERT into InnoDB table should be equally fast regardless of table size.

Comment: my main problem is not that the overall data is too huge, but the data of the last 24 hours until 7 days. Because on those durations we are making different reads. As long our business doesn't grow unexpected much, it will stay the same data in those durations. The problem is that queries now need to search 250.000 entries in last 7 days instead of 170.000 before we started in UK. As it worked perfectly before, I hoped to get the same by partitioning the countries. Bad idea?

Comment: If I got you right it might be better to make a partition for last 7 days and one for older data. Right? In this case we would ne a shell script that runs every night and places data older than 7 days to the other partition. What do you think about that approach?

Comment: You can have partition for each week (with partition names for example `201501` to `201548`). No need to move data between the partitions. Then MySQL would use only the partitions needed for each query. Also consider pre-computing aggregate tables for those 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `PARTITION` simply because you think it might speed things up.  It won't.

There are only 4 cases (that I know of) where `PARTITIONing` will speed up a system.  My [*blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) covers, in detail, the dropping "old" data as one of the useful cases, plus mentions the other 3.

I hope your `country_id` is a 2-byte "country code", not a 4-byte `INT`.

That the heck is a `click_id`?

In general high-traffic counters (eg, click counters) should be in a separate table with perhaps nothing more than an id and a counter.  This takes a load off the much-bulkier main table and avoids some categories of locks.

I can see *no* use for partitioning on country_id.

"7 days plus 'older'" -- There is a problem with this.  Tomorrow you will want to move a day's worth of data into the *big* "older" partition.  That involves `REORGANIZE PARTITION`, which will copy *all* of "older" over.  Too slow, and blocks the entire table.  I've done such, but I had to make sure there was a "maintenance window" during which I could do it.

> All our Reads and Inserts have country_id in WHERE clause.

Let's see some typical `SELECTs`.  Do they always have a `GROUP BY day`?  If so, then summary tables for each day may be warranted.  This will greatly offload the `SELECT` activity on the Fact table and move it to the smaller, better indexed summary table(s).  [*another blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).